# What is faster jQuery.load or jQuery.ajax() when loading HTML from PHP file?

Tags: ajax, performance, jquery, jquery-load

I have PHP file named "content.php" prepared for both kind of requests, just as an example:

```
<?php
  // Id params passed via GET method
  $get = $_GET['param'];
  switch ($get) {
    case "param_value":
?>
  <div data-param="<?php echo $get; ?>">
    // My HTML content here
  </div>
<?php
      break;
    case default:
      break;
  }

  // Id params passed via POST method
  $post = $_POST['param'];
  if ($post != "") {
    $data['output'] = '
      <div data-param="<?php echo $get; ?>">
        // My HTML content here
      </div>
    ';
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
?>
```

And than I have Javascript file, from which I am making an AJAX call to PHP:

```
var oWrapper = jQuery("#wrapper"),

// Loading HTML via jQuery.load() function
    sParams = jQuery.param({ param: "value" });
oWrapper.load("/content.php?" + sParams, function () {
  console.log("content loaded via load()");
});

// Loading HTML via jQuery.ajax() function
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/content.php",
  cache: false,
  data: { "param": "value" },
  success: function (data) {
    oWrapper.html(data.output);
    console.log("content loaded via ajax()");
  }
});
```

**Which way is faster?**

Besides the speed of requests and returns, I wish to know **which way is better for security** of the app?!

Comment: `.load` is just shorthand for `$.ajax` (and `$(element).html(data)`),  there's no other difference.  You can also use `$.post('/content.php', { "param": "value" }, function(){}, 'json');` or `$.getJSON("/content.php?" + sParams, function(){});` which are also just shorthand for `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ways do pretty much exactly the same thing.

Internally, `$(selector).load()` uses `$.ajax()` to get the data, then `$(selector).html()` to set the html of the selected element to the response of the `$.ajax()` call.

If you are loading html into an element, use `$(selector).load()` because it is more readable. One is just as secure and as fast as the other.

**Note:** Internally jQuery now uses `$.parseHTML()` rather than `$(selector).html()` to convert the string to html. This doesn't really change anything though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics but I dont't think there is a difference in security. load() and get() are "optimized" versions of ajax() so they will always be faster and better but I don't you or your visitors will ever feel the difference in a query like yours